# interface problem for image recognition

Tags: import, image, machine-learning

I made the following code that should recognize the image imported from the pc. If I do it for the first time it's fine, but if I load a second image it leaves me the name of the previous one. You could check the code and tell me where I'm wrong. Thanks for your help.

```
Row[{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[file]], Dynamic[file]}]
Button["Load file", im = Import[file]]
Dynamic[im]
Row[{"Si tratta di un ", 
  ImageIdentify[im, 
   Entity["Species", "Infraspecies:CanisLupusFamiliaris"]]}]
```

Comment: Please link your cross-posts so that others (1) don't have to do it for you and (2) can keep track of all prior responses. As it is, I am getting ready to start voting to close, since this request has been ignored several times now.

Comment: I do not know how to do.

Comment: In order to link to cross-posts, do as follows: (1) In the second post, add a link (URL) to the first post. (2) Return to the first post, hid "edit", and add a link to the second post. For example, the link to this post is https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189326/interface-problem-for-image-recognition?noredirect=1#comment493401_189326 (there are ways to make shorter hot links but that is not a necessity).